# Apache CXF 2.6.13 does not generate java classes

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl, cxf

I have a wsdl document from which I want to generate java classes into a client project. I do these steps:

I have the wsdl file into a dynamic web project inside Eclipse;

- I create a new dynamic web project in Eclipse.
- Right click on the wsdl file on the first project, "Web Services" -> "Generate Client"
- On configuration client I select the new dynamic web project I just created;
- On Web service runtime - Apache CXF 2.x
- On Server runtime - Tomcat 6.0
- I also check the box "Monitor Web Service"

After I do all these steps it opens the web client into a localhost browser inside Eclipse, but the classes are not generated in the new project.

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think it wont create the java files ..u need to use wsdltojava command ..check this http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html

Comment: Okay, so have you used this? Can you please help me?

Comment: are practicing any online example or your own..who developed that WSDL...By using which API they have used..IS it JAX-RPC or JAX-WS ?? And Which Implementation ?

Comment: It is JAX-WS. What do you mean by which implementation? When I created the client I selected all the options for WSDL2JAVA present there. But it still doesn't create any classes. I also specified to create them into src folder...

Comment: ok fror jax-WS U CAN USE THIS COMMAND in cmd prompt             "wsimport -d  src -keep -verbose http://example.com/webservice?wsdl"

Comment: thanks, @Naren for help! I managed to select the commands from eclipse and it worked fine. I wasn't selecting correctly the package, which was a zip (default), so it couldn't actually create the classes in src.